# Something about Riesz representation. Functioanl analysis...Kreysaig

Tags: functional-analysis

[image: Page 190]

[image: Page 191]

My question is why does [image] true.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are taking the supremum over a larger set on the left hand side, not just the range of $S$, yielding the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Fact: If $A\subseteq B,$ then $\sup A\leq \sup B.$

Since the linear operator $S$ is not onto, therefore range of $S$ is a subset of $H_2.$

As supremum is monotone, hence supremum over $S$ is less than supremum over $H_2.$